# Python to copy Excel cell range (with formatting intact) or image of Excel sheet to email html body WITHOUT pywin32

Tags: python, excel, email, xlsxwriter, smtplib

I am using Python script in Linux server to automatically send out email based on cron schedule.

So far, I am using pandas and xlsxwriter to generate an Excel with one sheet only into a folder in the server and using smtplib and email.mime library to send out email with html body and the Excel as attachment which is working fine.

However, I would like the email body to contain a copy of the Excel cell table or image whichever is fine as long as the formatting that I have done on the Excel with xlsxwriter is preserved when viewed in the email body.

Most of the sources I found (win32com.client or excel2img) requires pywin32 library which does not work in Linux so I am simply asking if there are alternatives.

Code that is currently using pywin32:

```
        import win32com.client as client
        from PIL import ImageGrab

        excel = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlsx_rpt_a)
        sheet = wb.Sheets[0]
        copyrange= sheet.Range('A1:R20')
        copyrange.CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=2)
        ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save(png_rpt_a)
        


        msg.attach(MIMEText(email_template, 'html'))

        fp = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), png_rpt_a), 'rb')
        msgImage1 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
        fp.close()
        msgImage1.add_header('Content-ID', '<'+png_file_rpt_a+'>')
        msg.attach(msgImage1)
```

html email body:

```
html_email_body = '''Hi all, sample text<br><br><img src="cid:'''+png_file_rpt_a+'''" style="display: block;margin: auto;width: 100%;"><br><br>'''
```

Comment: What is your code, error and expected result?

Comment: I added part of my code in the thread, there is no error at the code but im not able to use this in Linux, so my issue is to have an alternative that can achieve the same result as the above code. Im expecting the email I sent to have a picture in the email body